# Unrecognized argument "--deletion-protection" for gcloud.compute.instances.update

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sdk

I've setup a one-click LAMP stack on Google Cloud Engine, and that created a VM instance that I'd like to [protect against accidental deletion](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/preventing-accidental-vm-deletion#toggling_deletion_protection_for_existing_instances)

However, whenever I try to run the command using the gcloud command line tool, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.update) unrecognized arguments: --deletion-protection
```

Did anyone ever got this to work? Is there a mistake in the documentation?

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you post the exact command you are running? Because I tried both the commands in the documentation and in both cases I succeed in setting up the protection:

```
gcloud compute instances create new-instance --deletion-protection

gcloud compute instances update instance-name --deletion-protection
```

On the other hand which is the version of the Google SDK you are using (check through `gcloud version`)? Mine it is "Google Cloud SDK 183.0.0"

You can consider to update it and retry with:

```
gcloud components update
```

Comment: Doh! I committed the cardinal sin here, didn't I? Simply needed to upgrade the Google SDK. Thanks!

Comment: It happens, do not worry! By the way I checked your page www.nibnut.com and I love the design, well done!